# Return ASP DDL or Telerik control

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm trying to write a more generic method that will populate either an ASP.NET dropdownlist OR a telerik RadComboBox with states.  I'd like to pass the control in as a parameter to the method.  I have a DataTable that holds all the states, which I loop through (see below) - I'd like to make this applicable to a Telerik RadComboBox - so I need to change the first parameter, and also the part where I Insert a new ListItem - for Telerik RadComboBox it is new RadComboBoxItem.  How can I do this?

```
public void PopulateStates(DropDownList ddlStates, string country)
{
    ddlStates.Items.Clear();
    DataLookup dl = new DataLookup();
    DataTable dt = dl.GetStatesByCountry(country);
    if (dt != null)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlStates.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(""));
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                ddlStates.Items.Add(new ListItem(dt.Rows[i]["STCD_Descr"].ToString(),
                    dt.Rows[i]["STCD_State_CD"].ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the telerik documentation & there doesn't seem to be common way of doing - what you are trying to do.

If it is possible, try using the databinding (setting the DataSource & calling DataBind).
Note: I haven't tried it. But I think that should be supported by both.

Answer (score 0):

Since ListBox and RadComboBox does not have common classes except for the "Control" class you will need to check the actual type.

How about the following code?

```
public void PopulateStates(Control ddl, string country)
{
    object listItem = new object();
    switch (ddl.GetType().Name)
    {
        case "RadComboBox":
            listItem = listItem as RadComboBoxItem;
            ddl = ddl as RadComboBox;
            break;
        case "ListBox":
            listItem = listItem as ListItem;
            ddl = ddl as ListBox;
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    // proceed with your code
}
```

Comment: This seems like it would work, however, when I try to do something like ddlStates.Items.Clear(); (in the "proceed with your code" area - it doesn't recognize that "Items" is a property since it doesn't know what type of control it is at that point - I get a compile time error.

Comment: Sorry, you are completely right! I was sleeping while writing this. It will won't work because the base class they share does not have a property called Items. The easiest solution I can see in the moment is to create 2 predefined methods, the first to accept radCombo and the other dropDown.